# Retrieve attachments from e-mail

Tags: email, software-rec

Looking for freeware which retrieve attachments from email. Save attachment to the disk, and after that remove email. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which mail client ? Outlook, Thunderbird etc.

Comment: Well, i don't need mail cliet as it is. I need just software without GUI, which I can run in order to retrieve attachements from email

Answer (score 3):

`munpack` will do just that.

> The munpack program reads each RFC-822
>   message filename and writes all
>   non-text MIME parts or split-uuencoded
>   files as files. If no filename
>   argument is given, munpack reads from
>   standard input.

( http://linux.die.net/man/1/munpack )

For Linux, most distros have it in package `mpack`. No idea if there's a Windows or Mac port.

It expects the email messages as simple text files, one file per email. If you save an email in "plain text" from most email clients, that's what you get. Also, if you have a "maildir" email folder, mails will be in the right format.

Otherwise, you'd first need to somehow retrieve the mails in text format from your mail provider. But that's another question...